# Google Play Service Leaderboard Continuously Popping Up

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have been trying to control when Google Play leaderboard sign in pops up and once the user is signed in Google Play services leaderboard popping up on launch and after resume. How can I do it? I have extended BaseGameActivity and implemented below to show the leaderboard

```
 if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
```

public int gameMode;

```
public static void showLeaderboard(int mode) {
    me.gameMode = mode;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (me.isSignedIn())
                me.onShowLeaderboard();
            else
                me.SignIn();
        }
    });
}

public static void submitScore(final int score) {
    me.gameMode = score / 1000000;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            me.onSubmitScore(score % 1000000);
        }
    });

}


   public void onShowLeaderboard() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

public void onSubmitScore(int score) {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        switch (gameMode) {
        case 1:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard1),
                    score);
            break;
        case 2:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard2),
                    score);
            break;
        case 3:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard3),
                    score);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

boolean verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced() {
    final boolean CHECK_PKGNAME = true; // set to false to disable check
                                        // (not recommended!)

    // Did the developer forget to change the package name?
    if (CHECK_PKGNAME && getPackageName().startsWith("com.google.example.")) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "*** Sample setup problem: "
                        + "package name cannot be com.google.example.*. Use your own "
                        + "package name.");
        return false;
    }

    // Did the developer forget to replace a placeholder ID?
    // int res_ids[] = new int[] {
    // R.string.app_id
    // };
    // for (int i : res_ids) {
    // if (getString(i).equalsIgnoreCase("ReplaceMe")) {
    // Log.e(TAG, "*** Sample setup problem: You must replace all " +
    // "placeholder IDs in the ids.xml file by your project's IDs.");
    // return false;
    // }
    // }
    return true;
}

public void SignIn() {
    if (!verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced()) {
        showAlert("Sample not set up correctly. See README.");
        return;
    }

    // start the sign-in flow
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Failed!");
    // Intent mainIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
    // FlappyBirdActivity.class);
    // FirstActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    // FirstActivity.this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Successed!");
    onShowLeaderboard();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved I have been trying to control when Google Play leaderboard sign in pops up and once the user is signed in Google Play services leaderboard popping up on launch and after resume. How can I do it? I have extended BaseGameActivity and implemented below to show the leaderboard

```
if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
public int gameMode;

public static void showLeaderboard(int mode) {
    me.gameMode = mode;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (me.isSignedIn())
                me.onShowLeaderboard();
            else
                me.SignIn();
        }
    });
}

public static void submitScore(final int score) {
    me.gameMode = score / 1000000;
    me.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            me.onSubmitScore(score % 1000000);
        }
    });

}


   public void onShowLeaderboard() {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        startActivityForResult(getGamesClient().getAllLeaderboardsIntent(),
                RC_UNUSED);
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

public void onSubmitScore(int score) {
    if (isSignedIn()) {
        switch (gameMode) {
        case 1:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard1),
                    score);
            break;
        case 2:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard2),
                    score);
            break;
        case 3:
            getGamesClient().submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard3),
                    score);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        showAlert(getString(R.string.signing_in));
        this.SignIn();
    }
}

boolean verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced() {
    final boolean CHECK_PKGNAME = true; // set to false to disable check
                                        // (not recommended!)

    // Did the developer forget to change the package name?
    if (CHECK_PKGNAME && getPackageName().startsWith("com.google.example.")) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "*** Sample setup problem: "
                        + "package name cannot be com.google.example.*. Use your own "
                        + "package name.");
        return false;
    }

    // Did the developer forget to replace a placeholder ID?
    // int res_ids[] = new int[] {
    // R.string.app_id
    // };
    // for (int i : res_ids) {
    // if (getString(i).equalsIgnoreCase("ReplaceMe")) {
    // Log.e(TAG, "*** Sample setup problem: You must replace all " +
    // "placeholder IDs in the ids.xml file by your project's IDs.");
    // return false;
    // }
    // }
    return true;
}

public void SignIn() {
    if (!verifyPlaceholderIdsReplaced()) {
        showAlert("Sample not set up correctly. See README.");
        return;
    }

    // start the sign-in flow
    beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}

@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Failed!");
    // Intent mainIntent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
    // FlappyBirdActivity.class);
    // FirstActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
    // FirstActivity.this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onSignInSucceeded() {
    System.out.println("SignIn Successed!");
    onShowLeaderboard();
}
```